# Automatically creating polygon shape around multi points of lat longs in shapefile and see it on map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am not a tech guru but we have lat longs of points (of meters). We have created a shapefile, I can see the points on a map.

How do we then automatically draw a shape (polygon) around them all?

Basically creating a map view from a table containing lat / longs.

Assume that I am using a Basic level licence of ArcGIS Desktop.

Comment: Are you trying to change the symbol for your points? Or are you trying to generate a bounding box or enclosing polygon around the extent of the points?

Comment: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/production-mapping/converting-points-to-lines-or-polygons.htm

Comment: It sounds like you may be wanting to create a convex hull. As per the [Tour] there should should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: @paul, I edited your question to what I thought was your main question. If you disagree with my edits, you can use the [edit] link under the question to change them.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on your point layer in ArcMap's table of contents and click `Properties...`

[image]

Click on the Symbology tab and click on the image of your current symbol under the section `Symbol`.
[image]

You have a wide variety of shapes and colors to customize how your points look.
[image]